# How SUM() function works in Crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports

I am developing jasper reports for available crystal reports. In crystal report I found some variable for which expression are given as below:

```
   Variable                          Expresion
  region_amt      Sum ({Command.CEILING_AMT},{Command.PARENT_REF_DATA_CODE} );
  reg_amt2        Sum ({@Annual Allocated Dollars},{Command.PARENT_REF_DATA_CODE});
```

For first var, datatype of ceiling_amount is number while PARENT_REF_DATA_CODE is of String type. Same case is with reg_amt2 variable.

So I am getting confused weather SUM is concatenation or arithmetic SUM operation?

Can someone please clarify on this? Also fields in detail band are grouped by PARENT_REF_DATA_CODE.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here as you said report is group by PARENT_REF_DATA_CODE.

Sum here means output of the formula is summing the values with respect to the group PARENT_REF_DATA_CODE.

Let me know if you need further information

Comment: I agree. First formula will display the Sum of all {Command.CEILING_AMT} for each PARENT_REF_DATA_CODE group...

Comment: @Siva Thanks for your response. I got it now :)